# Javascript SyntaxError redeclaration of class

Tags: javascript

i'm starting using Javascript OOP, i writed my first class but i get an message error in the console

this is Class :

```
class Quote{

deleteQuote(callback){
    $('tr#'+callback.quoteid).hide('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}}

var Quote = new Quote();
```

this is the error :

```
SyntaxError: redeclaration of class Quote quote.js:9:4note: Previously declared at line 1, column 6
```

Comment: Use some other name for your variable. A scope can't have two variables with same name.

Comment: @MaheerAli i don't think this is true in all cases, in a scope you can have two variables with same name i.e, `var a = 20; var a = 30;`, even you can have `function a (){}; var a =30;`

Comment: @CodeManiac All the `a` are same. The code `var a = 20; var a = 30;` will be `var a; 
a = 20; a = 30 `.(hoisting). You can't declare a variable with same name twice in a scope

Comment: @CodeManiac Because `let,const`  and `class` are ES6 features so they are not hoisted in way that `var` does. If the class would be create using `function` declaration and `var` would be used instead of const there would be no error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the variable name, because classes are also variables in javascript

`var Quote = new Quote();`

to any other name like

`var quote = new Quote();`